# Twitter Bootstrap 2 breaks Rails 3.1 page scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, twitter-bootstrap

In attempting to upgrade to Bootstrap 2 (using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem), it seems that page-specific scripts are rendered unusable: all scripts must be loaded from the Asset Pipeline to work. Even a simple $ alert function called from a page script tag doesn't appear to load, even if yielded into the head after the AP loads. The original Bootstrap played fine with page scripts.

I understand that scripts should usually be loaded through the AP as a practice, but has anyone else experienced this behavior, and is this something that can be remedied easily, or is this something unique to my setup? (Rails 3.1.3, rvm, ruby 1.9.3, xCode 4.1)

A git reset solved the issue, but I'd rather upgrade and use the new TB features....

Thanks for any insights or thoughts about how to track down the issue.

Comment: It appears to have to do with the version of jquery-rails being used, along with its dependencies. Without 2.0.1, the issue could be recreated in a test app. FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using rails 3.1.3 the new gem works fine for me on rails 3.2.2 so it should be that your jquery-rails gem might not be using the latest jquery. so try upgrading cos the new gem works with the latest version of jquery

Comment: Success! Also had conflicts with some older gems. Thanks.